# Wii Shop Channel out of service

Tags: nintendo-wii

I have just connected my old Wii and when I go to the shop (to download demos) it says its out of service. Is it turned off forever or can I somehow use it?

Answer (score 3):

The Wii Shop has been discontinued. As of January 30, 2019, Wii users are no longer able to make purchases in the shop.

Users *should* be able to continue to download previously purchased software, *however* as of 16th March 2022, the Wii Shop systems have been "undergoing maintenance", On 22nd May, 2022, Nintendo responded they have "nothing to announce" as to progress on restoring the service.

Suffice to say it's probably not coming back.

---

- [Wii Shop Channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_Shop_Channel) - (Wikipedia), accessed 25 May 2022
- [Nintendo Responds To Wii And DSi Shop Channel Outages](https://www.nintendolife.com/news/2022/05/nintendo-responds-to-wii-and-dsi-shop-channel-outages) (Liam Doolan, 22 May 2022, Eurogamer) - accessed 25 May 2022

Comment: If you're still after online services for the Wii, I recommend setting up Homebrew, Priiloader and RiiConnect24. Homebrew probably needs no introduction. Wiimmfi (through Priiloader) enables online services for games, and RiiConnect24 will (among other things) make channels like Forecast and News work again. [This site](https://wii.guide/get-started) can guide you through the process.